# How to return an array from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm searching for a better solution to making an AJAX call with jQuery, having the PHP file return an array, and have it come out client-side as a Javascript array. Here is what I have been doing this:

PHP File (Example.php):

```
<?php
    $id_numbers = array('NES-ZL','NES-AL','SNS-ZL');

    for ($i=0; $i<count($the_array); $i++){
        echo $id_numbers[$i];
        echo '|';
    }
?>
```

JS File:

```
id_numbers = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url:"Example.php",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(msg){
        id_numbers = msg.split('|');
    }
});
```

My current method is just a little too convoluted for my taste.

What I'd like to do is to be able to just

```
return $id_numbers;
```

on the PHP side and directly translate it to a Javascript array after the AJAX call.

Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Use [JSON](http://json.org/) to transfer data types (arrays and objects) between client and server.

In PHP:

- [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

In JavaScript:

- [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

PHP:

```
echo json_encode($id_numbers);
```

JavaScript:

```
id_numbers = JSON.parse(msg);
```

As Wolfgang mentioned, you can give a fourth parameter to jQuery to automatically decode JSON for you.

```
id_numbers = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url:"Example.php",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(msg){
        id_numbers = msg;
    },
    dataType:"json"
});
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful! It will definitely make everything simpler and prettier.

Comment: @k_sel it's pretty much an industry standard. Everyone uses this for AJAX. You'll notice that JSON is also valid JavaScript.

Comment: Don't forget to use `async: false`

Comment: For other noobs: The response must be pure json. I had some HTML in it, a comment. No error message, just failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really helpful for me

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP. You can get $.ajax to recognize this with the dataType: "json" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

@Xeon06, nice but just as a fyi for those that read this thread and tried like me...
when returning the array from php => `json_encode($theArray)`. converts to a string which to me isn't easy to manipulate esp for soft js users like myself.

Inside js, you are trying to get the array values and/or keys of the array u r better off using JSON.parse as in `var jsArray = JSON.parse(data)` where data is return array from php. the json encoded string is converted to js object that can now be manipulated easily.

e.g.
foo={one:1, two:2, three:3} - gotten after JSON.parse

`for (key in foo){ console.log("foo["+ key +"]="+ foo[key]) }` - prints to ur firebug console. voila!

Comment: Weird as it may be, if you are working with multidimensional arrays, try and `json_encode` the inner arrays, thus `$parent_array = array (json_encode($child_array));` . It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `json_encode` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It is available as of PHP 5.2. Use the parameter `dataType: 'json'` to have it parsed for you. You'll have the Object as the first argument in success then. For further information have a look at the jQuery-documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Php has a super sexy function for this, just pass the array to it:

```
$json = json_encode($var);

$.ajax({
url:"Example.php",
type:"POST",
dataType : "json",
success:function(msg){
    console.info(msg);
}
});
```

simples :)

Answer (score 0):

well, I know that I'm a bit too late, but I tried all of your solutions and with no success!
So here is how I managed to do it.
First of all, I'm working on an Asp.Net MVC project.
The Only thing I changed was in my c# method `getInvitation`:

```cs
public ActionResult getInvitation (Guid s_ID)
{
    using (var db = new cRM_Verband_BWEntities())
    {
        var listSidsMit = (from data in db.TERMINEINLADUNGEN where data.RECID_KOMMUNIKATIONEN == s_ID select data.RECID_MITARBEITER.ToString()).ToArray();
        return Json(listSidsMit);
    }
}
```

SuccessFunction in JS :

```js
function successFunction(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

I changed the Method Type from `string[]` to `ActionResult` and of course at the end I wrapped my array `listSidsMit` with the Json method.