# Can anyone help me catch a syntax error in jquery

Tags: php, ajax, json

In my console I keep getting a syntax error on line 10. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Thank you so much for the help.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    // Skill sort on change 
    $('#order_by').on('change', function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "sort_skill_be.php", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: { skill: this.value }, 
            error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(errorThrown);  // SYNTAX ERROR HERE
            }, 
            success: function (result) { 
                alert(result[0].skill); 
                alert('i got here'); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

**ERROR MSG**
`SyntaxError {}`

Thank you so much for your help and assistance.

When I alert the errorThrown I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

EDIT
**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'database.php';
$skill_sort = $_POST['skill'];
sortSkill($skill_sort);
?>


function sortSkill($skill){
    // If All skill is selected display posts normally
    if ($skill == 'All'){
        displayPosts();
        exit;
    }
    $db = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN posts 
            ON users.idUsers = posts.fkuser 
            WHERE posts.fkuser IS NOT NULL and users.skill=:skill
            ORDER BY date DESC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':skill' => $skill));      
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
        // Nothing has returned
        unset($_SESSION['recent_posts']); // Reset session of posts if no posts appear.
    } 
    else
    {
        $recent_posts = helpFetchPostInfo($stmt);
        return $recent_posts;
    }
}




 // IS THIS CORRECT??
function helpFetchPostInfo($stmt){
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $recent_posts = array();
    foreach ($results as $row){
        $post = array(
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'steam' => $row['steam'],
            'skill' => $row['skill'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'date' => $row['date'],
        );
        array_push($recent_posts, $post);
    }
    return json_encode($recent_posts); 
}

?>
```

**Headers / Network from browser**

```
Request URL:http://zeex/sort_skill_be.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=9db38628119ef72c7be1c20eaa5da13d
Host:zeex
Origin:http://zeex
Referer:http://zeex/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
skill:High
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 21 Jun 2013 01:40:15 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4
```

Comment: What does the response look like? Show us the source which the server sent.

Comment: Open chrome dev tools, "Sources" tab, turn on "break on the unhandled exeption" mode, refresh the page and stop guessing

Comment: How exactly do I turn on break on the unhandled exception

Comment: I don't see a syntax error in your js, I think you have another problem and it might be on the server side, why don't you try to catch the variable skill the normal way $_post['skill'] ?

Comment: @CME64 Sorry I do not know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594923/chrome-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: here is your code on jsbin it is working fine : http://jsbin.com/uyonit/1/edit (the error message is due to the origin of the ajax)

Comment: what kind of server are you using ? it looks like php,, apache ?

Comment: I am using php apache.

Comment: yes, the sent query can be received on the server side usign $vriable = $_POST["skill"]; check this out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Comment: @Sushanth-- is right, when I remove the datatype:json the error goes away and I get another error saying it does not recognize skill `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skill' of undefined `

Comment: first debug the reception on the server side if you receive that variable that means your processing for information is not right on the server .. try echoing it

Comment: Looks like your response is not a valid `json` string.. try pasting it in jslint and see if it is valid

Comment: @CME64 - just FYI, people on this site like to flame for referencing w3schools. You would likely have suffered an assault of downvotes if that was in an answer

Comment: Ah.. so I cannot pass an array of an array to JSON? im guessing.

Comment: I'm trying to help you here, if you don't want the help .. I have no problem .. and check it out never down-voted !

Comment: @CME64 don't worry your helping, thanks for your time. But now I feel it has something to do with me incorrectly using JSON object

Comment: what do you get when you try to print the $skill ?

Comment: In PHP I do get the correct skill, but in jquery it is not allowing me to access it.

Comment: I am sure it has to do with something right here `$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $recent_posts = array();
 foreach ($results as $row){
  $post = array(
   'username' => $row['username'],
   'steam' => $row['steam'],
   'skill' => $row['skill'],
   'description' => $row['description'],
   'date' => $row['date'],
  );
  array_push($recent_posts, $post);
 }
 return json_encode($recent_posts);`

Comment: Thanks for the code, though I can't see where you are `echo`ing anything. However, the serverside code is not that interesting, please post *what the browser received* instead. You can view it in the network tab of the devtools.

Comment: ok I don't know how you planned it, but this is how to use json ,, you send your objects normally and on the server-side it will be received as the original object, the server then responds with an object (array,string .. ) then the dataType: 'json' will convert your response into json objects .. default uses object d

Comment: also it will be interesting for you to check out contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'

Comment: @Bergi I added my browser sent information

Comment: @CME64 what exactly do you mean / how do I check out the contentType, do I just add it to the ajax code?

Comment: yes, it helped me some times, it forces the response to be parsed as json http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ( not w3s)

Comment: Thanks. Well, in the first request, `skill:High` is not valid JSON, and the second one has `Content-Length:0`. So where does your PHP script actually output anything?

Comment: Thanks I added it, but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Is my PHP suppose to output something? I thought its suppose to store as a JSON object as I would be able to use the data in jquery from the php.

Comment: @Bergi is there a better way for me to store the information and access it?
I have made another thread to try to figure out if I am doing this ajax stuff correctly I am still new at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823925/how-to-return-an-array-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: (First, sorry, I didn't notice that `skill:High` is the *request* body. It's fine. The empty answer is not) Of course the PHP is supposed to output something. It should send the requested data to the browser, that's what you asked it to do (didn't you?). Your `success` callback even *expects* some data back (an array with an object inside). Of course the server might store something in the DB and do anything else, but the primary purpose of your request seems to be to *get data back*.

Comment: You PHP needs to `echo` the result of `sortSkill(...)`.

Comment: (+1 to @Vedran) …and set the `Content-Type` response header to `application/json`