# Can I encode an array of 'array objects' in php when using json/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello I was wondering if this is possible?

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $recent_posts = array();
    foreach ($results as $row){
        $post = array(
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'steam' => $row['steam'],
            'skill' => $row['skill'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'date' => $row['date'],
        );
        array_push($recent_posts, $post);
    }
    return json_encode($recent_posts);
```

If this is possible how exactly do I access it in jquery?
    $

```
('#order_by').on('change', function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "sort_skill_be.php", 
            data: { skill: this.value }, 
            error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(errorThrown); 
                //alert(errorThrown);
            }, 
            success: function (result) { 
                alert(result[0].skill);  // CAN I ACCESS IT LIKE THIS?
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting weird errors. When I added `datatype:json` I keep getting problems. So I feel I am handling this incorrectly, Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you actually specifying `application/json` (or whatever the cool kids use) as the content type?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I have dataType json, please refer to my previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226224/can-anyone-help-me-catch-a-syntax-error-in-jquery

Comment: @cHao how do I specify it? thanks for the reply guys

Comment: @AustinTruong: In PHP?  `header("Content-Type: application/json");` before you generate any output.

Comment: Where are you outputting the json?

Comment: Another big difference is you will want to echo out the content as opposed to returning it

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I will make some changes when I get the chance to!

Comment: have you echo the json_encode array in sort_skill_be.php?

Comment: You should be able to access it the way you have it as long as result contains the indexes you try to display, along with the suggestions by @cHao , you should also declare the content type in the jQuery ajax request by adding  `contentType: "application/json",` after `url: "sort_skill_be.php",`