# How to pull selected attribute data from ajax called data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, active-directory

i have been able to fetch data with an ajax call from active directory .The php file used to fetch data from active directory is below :

```html
<?php
$username   = 'maxxxxxxx';
$password   = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$server = 'ldap://xxxxxxx';
$domain = '@asia.xxxxxx.com';
$port       = 389;

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($server, $port);

if (! $ldap_connection)
{
    echo '<p>LDAP SERVER CONNECTION FAILED</p>';
    exit;
}

// Help talking to AD
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$ldap_bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $username.$domain, $password);

if (! $ldap_bind)
{
    echo '<p>LDAP BINDING FAILED</p>';
    exit;
}
else
{
  echo 'login successful';
}

$base_dn = "OU=Employees,OU=Accounts,OU=India,DC=asia,DC=xxxxx,DC=com";

$dispname="Mark Hwett";


$filter ="(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=$dispname))";

$attr = array("sn","givenname","employeeid","distinguishedname","displayname","samaccountName","department","manager","mail","title","thumbnailphoto");

$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection,$base_dn,$filter,$attr);

$rescount = ldap_count_entries($ldap_connection,$result);

$data = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection,$result);


if ($data["count"] > 0)
{
for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++)
{
echo "<p> sn: " . $data[$i]["sn"][0]."<br/>";
echo "givenname: ". $data[$i]["givenname"][0] ."<br/>" ;
echo "employeeID: " . $data[$i]["employeeid"][0]."<br/>";
echo "distinguishedName: " . $data[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]."<br/>";
echo "displayName: " . $data[$i]["displayname"][0]."<br/>";
echo "sAMAccountName: " . $data[$i]["samaccountname"][0]."<br/>";
echo "department: ". $data[$i]["department"][0]."<br/>";
echo "manager: " .$data[$i]["manager"][0]."<br/>";
echo "mail: ". $data[$i]["mail"][0]."<br/>";
echo "title: " .$data[$i]["title"][0]."<br/>";
//echo "photo: " .$data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0]."<br/>";


// echo "<br/><br/>";
}
}
else
        {
            echo "<p>No results found!</p>";
        }


?>
```

The browser console shows that the above php returns this :

```html
<p> sn: xxxxxx<br/>givenname: xxxxx<br/>
employeeID: 0050<br/
>distinguishedName: CN=xxxx xxxxx,OU=Employees,OU=Accounts,OU=India,DC=asia,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=com<br/>
displayName: Mark Hewettk<br/>sAMAccountName: xxxxxxx<br/>
department: xxxxx<br/>manager: CN=xxxxxx xxxxxxx,OU=Employees,OU=Accounts,OU=India,DC=asia,DC=xxxx,DC=com
<br/>
mail: mhewettk@abc.com<br/>
title: xyz<br/>
```

I want to take only some attributes from  above data like mail,displayname etc and display in my HTML :

```html
  <h2 class="profile__name" id="emailOfUser">Email : </h2>
```

**Now the problem is the jquery that I have used here :**

```html
$('.leaderboard li').on('click', function () {
 $.ajax({
 url: "../popupData/activedirectory.php", // your script above a little adjusted
 type: "POST",
 data: {id:$(this).find('.parent-div').data('name')},
 success: function(data){
 console.log(data);

 $('#popup').fadeIn();
 
$('#emailOfUser').html(data); //this line displays all data whereas I want to select only email,displayname from the above console data



//whatever you want to fetch ......
 // etc ..
 },
 error: function(){
 alert('failed, possible script does not exist');
 }
 });
 });
```

**problem is this :**

```html
$('#emailOfUser').html(data);
```

**this line displays all data whereas I want to select only email,displayname from the above console data**

**kindly help me how to select only desired attribute  data from the above browser console data.**

I eve tried to convert it to JSON following this.but no luck.[How to return an array from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823925/how-to-return-an-array-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the data to the client as a string of HTML you could pass the data as a simple JSON-Object:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

That way you can process the data much easier on the client side as it is already in a format that JavaScript understands.

Something like...

```
$.ajax({
   url: "../popupData/activedirectory.php"
   ...
}).then(function(response) {
   // now you have access to the data as a plain JS-Object
   $('#emailOfUser').html(response.email + " - " + response.displayname);
});
```

... should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the response.but I am getting errors "saying possible script doesnot exist". I ahve mag ethe following changes to the .php file above http://pastebin.com/fBDJqKFQ    AND the following changes to the jquery http://pastebin.com/JTHeAjsi

Comment: Where do u think is the mistake ?

Comment: can you post a link to the output of console.log?

Comment: its in my local drive, otherwise would have shared the link.the console displays the data as mentioned above in the second snippet.i have copied and pasted it from console only.

Comment: Can you check in the network-tab of the browser devtools what the response from the server looks like? Do you even get a response? Did you change any parameters of the $.ajax-call?

Comment: its all okay.i have checked otherwise i wiuldnot get the data in the browser console.

Comment: are files in the pastebinn link okay ?

Comment: If jQuery only executes the error-callback for your ajax-call ("saying possible script doesnot exist"), there must be something wrong with the server-response. Sorry if I'm not following you ...the pastebin links you posted only contain the code, not the response-data itself(?).