# "undefined" after passing JSON array via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

With the use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823995/8920690) I appear to have got the passing of an array from one PHP file to another working with AJAX Javascript.

However, if I try to use the data at all, it comes back as "undefined".

Am I missing a step?

ajax.php:

```
<?php
  $letters = array('A','B','C');
  echo json_encode($letters);
?>
```

JS:

```
function loadDoc() {
        letters = new Array();
        $.ajax({
                url:"ajax.php",
                type:"POST",
                success:function(msg){
                        letters = msg;
                },
                dataType:"json"
        });
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = letters[0];
  }
```

Ultimately I just want to have the array back in the format ['A', 'B', 'C'] for use with chart.js.

Comment: You can use a callback function

Comment: Move the `innerHTML` assignment inside success callback. You can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered. Also set dataType

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Cut and paste it

Comment: @charlietfl Moving it inside worked thanks. Is the dataType not set with the dataType:"json" I have there? And also, is the letters array now in the format ['A', 'B', 'C']? Or do I need to convert it to that?

Comment: Oh yes it is (dataType)...am so used to seeing it above success I missed it. No worries there

Comment: The dataType;json means you have an array parsed from json inside the success already. That array can be any nested structure you want

Comment: @charlietfl Perfect thank you so much!

Comment: @charlietfl Is it possible to pass two arrays through at the same time? All working perfectly with one but if I try and pass a second one in the same way in same function it fails ?

Comment: Only if they are nested in an outer object. Can only do one `echo json_encode($output)`

Comment: @charlietfl Created an array of the two arrays and sent that over, worked perfectly.