# convert array into json using php , and retrive json using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I created json using php:

```
 $arr = [];
    foreach($userinfo as $record) {
        $arr[] = array(
           'BAid' => $record->getBAid(),
           'BCid' => $record->getBCid(),
          'BAusername'=>$record->getBAusername(),
          'BAdisplay_name'=>$record->getBAdisplay_name(),
          'BAtel'=>$record->getBAmobile(),
          'BAimg'=>$record->getBAimg(),
          'BArole' => $record->getBArole()
      );}

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

and I used the following code to retrieve the result of json, and I want to put it inside the html table.

```
 $.ajax({
            url :"admin=search",
            type: "POST",
            data: {search:name },
            success: function (data) {
              //  alert(data);
                const myArrStr = JSON.stringify(data);

                console.log(data);

            }
        })
```

Comment: JSON is a string, you've to use `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON string to an object.

Comment: I used JSOn.pars, it does not work for me as well.

Comment: Then at first, take a look at the Network tab in the DevTools. Was the response received with status 200? You can also see the actual content of the body of the response. And last, open the console to see if there was an error when parsing the JSON.

Comment: Why you specified method POST? It should be GET, IMHO: even if you plan to store results in a variable, then to show them in a table.

Comment: @FedericoMoretti Why should the method be GET? There's no obvious reason in the provided code. Only that the URL parameter is somewhat weird ...

Comment: [{"BAid":"3","BCid":"29","BAusername":"pc","BAdisplay_name":"pc","BAtel":"0255","BAimg":"1583616547.png","BArole":"1"}] 
I get this result in console, but how put them inside html table.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Are you not getting the desired response or you don't know how to place the contents into a table?

Comment: You return JSON from the PHP code so just add `dataType: 'json',` to the Ajax call and jquery will do all the work for you and deliver you an Javascript object/array of objects into the `data` variable

Comment: _NOTE_ using `JSON.stringify` is doing the exact oposite of what you want! _The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string_

Comment: @Teemu it doesn’t need to POST anything, anywhere: maybe I didn’t understand OP, but AFAIK there’s a PHP function that generates a JSON array with the data; JavaScript should just GET it and parse it to show results in a table…

Comment: @FedericoMoretti I send every AJAX request using post, nevertheless something will be stored on the server or not (because of the CSRF-check). There might also be something using the post method in the OP's real code, which is not shown to us, because it would just be irrelevant to the task.

Comment: @El_Vanja, yes, I want to put this result inside an html table. that is it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly,  it does not change anything, but the result will be empty if I add dataType: 'json';

Answer (score 1):

Try and use:

```
var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
```

This will return the `json` in a javascript array.
Then you can use `data_array.BAid` for example to output the data.

**EDIT:**
If this does not help you, take a loot over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823991/10791031

Comment: return undefined variable. using this way.

Answer (score 1):

You've to set `headers` to tell the browsers that requested endpoint is returning a `json` response.
So you can use the below code to set the headers.

```
$data = $arr
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: it does not solve my problem, thank you.